# How to remove subdirectory in wordpress using htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to change the url from:

```
http://example.com/*/a/any.html
http://example.com/*/b/any.html
http://example.com/*/c/any.html
```

to:

```
http://example.com/a/any.html
http://example.com/b/any.html
http://example.com/c/any.html
```

and if access directly to:

```
http://example.com/a/any.html
http://example.com/b/any.html
http://example.com/c/any.html
```

keep it that way

thank you all for your help in advance

Comment: "I need to rewrite" - presumably you mean "redirect"?

Comment: can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `/subdir` is the subdirectory you need to remove then you can try something like the following at the top of your root `.htaccess` file, before the existing WordPress directives:

```
RewriteRule ^subdir(/(a|b|c)/[\w-]+\.html)$ $1 [R=302,L]
```

If the *subdirectory* is literally any subdirectory then try the following instead:

```
RewriteRule ^[^/]+(/(a|b|c)/[\w-]+\.html)$ $1 [R=302,L]
```

Comment: Thank you but this doesnt work if the subdirectory has different names

Comment: @miguelangellopezcarrizales I've updated my answer to include a solution for _any_ subdirectory.

Comment: Thank you for you time an dedication, i make this one that works 

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(a|b|c)/(.*)$ $2/$3 [R=301,L]

Comment: @miguelangellopezcarrizales Ok, but there's no need to capture the first path segment (directory), since this is being discarded. It's also dependent on `RewriteBase` being set. And it also matches more than just `.html` files, as stated in the question - it matches any URL-path, including multiple path segments?