# How to redirect specific subdirectory name in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I need to redirect from:

```
http://example.com/*/this/any.html
http://example.com/*/*/this/any.html
http://example.com/*/*/*/this/any.html
```

to:

```
http://example.com/this/any.html
```

Comment: This seems to be very closely related to your earlier question... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70551678/how-to-remove-subdirectory-in-wordpress-using-htaccess ?

Comment: Do the `*` represent _any_ path segment? Is `this` a static name? And `any` is literally _any_ file basename?

Comment: thats right men

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like the following using mod_rewrite at the top of the root `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(?:[^/]+/){1,3}(this/[\w-]+\.html)$ /$1 [R=302,L]
```

`any.html` - the file basename (`any`) is permitted to contain the following characters: `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, `_` (underscore) and `-` (hypen)

Comment: Thank you very much but this one works very well

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/this/(.*)$ /this/$2 [R=301,L]

Comment: @miguelangellopezcarrizales You're welcome, although that doesn't appear to match the 2nd and 3rd examples in your question?